# GWT scroll bar over the all window

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a global presenter that contains a Header Footer and the main content slots, when header always on the top, footer always on the bottom...

My question is: **How can i add scroll bar to my Global Presenter?**

I know that there were a lot of questions like this but i cant find the right answer for me.

I have UiBinder that has the code:

```
    <g:RootLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
    <g:layer left="0px" right="0px" top="0px" bottom="0px">
        <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM">
            <g:north size="5.0">
                <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="headerContentPanel" />
            </g:north>
            <g:center size="1.0">
                <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainContentPanel" />
            </g:center>
            <g:south size="1.5">
                <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="footerContentPanel" />
            </g:south>
        </g:DockLayoutPanel>
    </g:layer>
</g:RootLayoutPanel>
```

I have tried to add ScrollPanel that is contains the RootLayotPanel or other panels.. but than all the inner panel receive size zero.

I have tried to use a vertical panel inside the scrollPanel but than I can't put the footer at the bottom.

Does someone has an answer?

==================================================================================

I succeeded to do it, here is my new code:

```
    <g:RootLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
    <g:layer>

        <g:ScrollPanel width="100%" height="100%">
            <g:DockPanel width="100%" horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER" verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE">
                <g:Dock direction="NORTH" >
                    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="headerContentPanel" />
                </g:Dock>
                <g:Dock direction="CENTER" verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE" horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER">
                    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainContentPanel" />
                </g:Dock>
                <g:Dock direction="SOUTH"  verticalAlignment="ALIGN_BOTTOM" horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER">
                    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="footerContentPanel" />
                </g:Dock>
            </g:DockPanel>
        </g:ScrollPanel>

    </g:layer>
</g:RootLayoutPanel>
```

But I have small problem: my footer isn't attached to bottom, no matter what i tried..
Does someone know the solution?

Comment: Hm I don't see point in putting scroll bar here as inner `DockLayoutPanel` will take up all of width/height of that layer. Since your layer is positioned `0px` from all 4 sides it will take 100% of your browser screen. Are you sure you want scroller around header and footer as well or **just** center panel?

Comment: Yes, I want scroller around header and footer. Like in facebook the header is also included in the scroller bar

Comment: OK, try wrapping that `DockLayoutPanel` with `ScrollPanel`. That should do the trick but currently I'm away from my dev computer and have no means of checking...

Comment: Thanks for help. But I have tried it already, and it doesn't work. It works only if the DockLayoutPanel has fix width and high (like 800px) I have tried to set the width and high to 100%, unfortunately with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout Panels do not work properly in scroll panels. But scoll panels can be used in Layout Panels:
For example to scrolling the center part:

> ```
>     <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM">
>         <g:north size="5.0">
>             <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="headerContentPanel" />
>         </g:north>
>         <g:center size="1.0">
>
>           <g:ScrollPanel>
>             <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainContentPanel" />
>           </g:ScrollPanel>
>
>         </g:center>
>         <g:south size="1.5">
>             <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="footerContentPanel" />
>         </g:south>
>     </g:DockLayoutPanel>
> ```

---

Another possibility is to use DockPanel instead Layout Panels.

If the header included in the scroll bar :

> ```
> <g:ScrollPanel>   
>    <g:DockPanel>
>       <g:Dock direction="NORTH" height="100px">
>           <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="headerContentPanel" />
>       </g:Dock>
>       <g:Dock direction="CENTER">
>           <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainContentPanel" />
>       </g:Dock>
>       <g:Dock direction="SOUTH" height="100px">
>           <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="footerContentPanel" />
>       </g:Dock>
>   </g:DockPanel> 
> </g:ScrollPanel>
> ```

And then put this in `RootLayoutPanel` or `RootPanel`

---

Or use DockPanel in Layout Panels.
For example: we want to have scrollable header and center part, but west panel and bottom always in view:

> ```
> <g:DockLayoutPanel width="100%">
>   <g:west size="100.0">
>      <g:Label>West side </g:Label>
>   </g:west>
>   <g:center>
>      <g:ScrollPanel>   
>         <g:DockPanel>
>           <g:Dock direction="NORTH" height="100px">
>             <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="headerContentPanel" />
>           </g:Dock>
>           <g:Dock direction="CENTER">
>             <g:FlowPanel ui:field="mainContentPanel" />
>           </g:Dock>
>         </g:DockPanel> 
>      </g:ScrollPanel>
>   </g:center>
>   <g:south size="50">
>      <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="footerContentPanel" />
>   </g:south >
> </g:DockLayoutPanel>
> ```

And then put this in `RootLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, very clear.. great answer! As I said i need to cover all my page with scroll bar. I succeeded to do it with your second solution, I edited my question up there, and you can see my code, but now i have another problem, my footer isn't attache to bottom, can you help me with it too?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe try using the height. verticalAlignments have no meaning without specifying the height. Example : <g:Dock direction="SOUTH" height="200px" ... >

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the GWT (UiBinder) syntax and all the cascaded layout for a moment. Just consider this simplified example:

- We have a window, let's say with a current height of 1000px.
- We have a container (just imagine a simple black box) that takes up 100% of the window height - so it has 1000px height.

In this case, there is nothing to scroll. So with scroll=auto there will be no scroll bar on the window. (Forget any possible scroll bars inside our black box.)

---

If you want a layout where the header stays on top, while everything else scrolls (with a scrollbar that takes up 100% height), you should probably start with a header with "position=fixed". So what you would do in HTML is this:

```
<div class="headerContent">My header</div>
<div class="everythingElse">
   <div class="mainContent">...</div>
   <div class="footerContent">My footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5.0em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.everythingElse {
  margin-top: 5.0em; /* Same as the height of the header */
}
```

You can do the same in GWT UiBinder. Just replace the divs with simple FlowPanels (if you like), and apply the css (with a UiBinder CSS class referenced using the `addStyleNames` attribute). No DockPanels needed. When the height of "everythingElse" exceeds the window height, the default setup of the body tag shows the scroll bar.